# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 - Intellisense

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

When I am inside an MVC Razor view in VS 2015 Update 1, I get a strange intellisense problem when writing out HTML helper classes. The intellisense drop down appears briefly and then disappears. I never had this issue in VS 2015 without update 1 or indeed any previous VS version. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: It is a bug, but see the answer I posted here for a helpful workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36723662/1238895

Answer (score 0):

Please try these command:

1)Devenv.exe /ResetSettings. It restores the IDE's default settings, optionally resets to the specified VSSettings file.

2) Devenv.exe /resetuserdata - Note, this requires you to reinstall all extensions

See if it helps to fix the issue and display intellisense.

Comment: I stumbled across this as this issue was annoying me. Unfortunately resetting the settings or user data doesn't change anything

Comment: I am pretty certain these fixes are not relevant to this issue - hence the lack of up-votes. They may fix other issues but not this one.