# cshtml Razor IntelliSense suggestions dissapear instantly

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have read and seen many IntelliSense problems related to Razor in cshtml files. Mostly that 'it is not working'. For me this is only the first 5 seconds, then everything is correct. But what bugs me is something very weird. I had it on one pc first, thought it was computer related, yet this is the second time it happens:

When I start typing, lets say `@Model`, as soon as I press the period button `.` I get the usual list of possible properties to select, but this list disappears instantly. It is a little flash of the list. Of course I want this to stay while I continue typing and choose the correct one when desired.
In a normal `.cs` file it is working fine, also in an `.js` file (AngularJS).
When I hit CTRL + Space it correctly shows the same list and it stays there, even when continue typing.

Very tiny but yet so annoying.

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.
Had the issue on Windows 10 and Windows 7 (fresh install on here, with version 2 update).

This question sums up everything I have tried (everything with at least +1) [Visual Studio 2015 Broken Razor Intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581666/visual-studio-2015-broken-razor-intellisense)

Answer (score 0):

There are many suggested solutions [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212901/vs-2015-razor-autocomplete-intellisense-dropdown-hides-immediately-after-dropdow/41128392#41128392)

But what worked for me, is to make sure the close parenthesis have space between the text I am typing.

Instead of...

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m.)`

Use...

`@Html.LabelFor(m => m. )`

The intellisense seems to get confused by touching close parenthesis.  Not ideal, but this was the only way I could get it to work for me consistently.